# Local Degree of smooth map vs Degree of a Covering

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, covering-spaces

Consider any two oriented connected closed smooth manifolds
$M, N$ of same dimension $n \ge 1$. Let $f : M \to N$ be a smooth map. Recall that a regular value of $f$ is a point $y \in Y$ such that the differential $D_xf^*$ of $f$ is invertible at each point of
$x \in f^{−1}(y)$. It is a basic result due to Sard that the complement in $N$ of the set of regular values has Lebesgue measure zero; in particular, the set of regular values of $f$ is dense , and so non-empty.
If $y \in N$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism around every $x \in f^{−1}(y)$; it follows that $f^{−1}(y)$ is discrete in $M$; since this fiber is also compact, it is
therefore finite. For $x \in f^{−1}(y)$ define $\epsilon_x(f)$ to be $1$ if $f$ is orientation preserving at $x$ and $−1$ if f is orientation reversing at $x$.

**Definition:** The local degree of $f$ at a regular value $y$ is the integer

$$\text{deg}(y)(f) = \sum_{x \in f^{−1}(y)} \epsilon_x(f) $$

In other words it's the difference of the number of points in the fiber at $y$ where $f$ in a neighbourhood of $x$ is orientation preserving minus the number of points where $f$ is locally orientation reversing.

Non assume that $f: M \to N$ is in addition a finite covering in topological sense. Then one can also define purely topologically the degree of $f$ to be  the number of elements in the fiber: $ \vert f^{−1}(y) \vert $

Question: Do these two definition coincide (up to $\pm 1 $ sign)? Or in equivalent terms, is a honest covering map (ie without any ramificational defects) always locally orientation preserving?

Comment: Yes, the two notions coincide, you do not even need a covering map for that. Hatcher has several exercises leading you to this result.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The $\epsilon_x(f)$ depend on the choice of orientations of $M, N$. If we reverse one of them, $\deg(y)(f)$ changes sign. Thus the number of elements in $f^{-1}(y)$ is the absolute value of $\deg(y)(f)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Of course, one should use the same choice of orientations to make the definitions agree. But OP assumed in the first line that manifolds are oriented, meaning a fixed choice of orientations. That said, the title question makes little sense.

Comment: yes the title is indeed rather misleading, sorry. @Moishe Kohan: could you tell me which concrete exercises in Hatcher provide the connectionbetween these two notations? Hatcher not introduces the first one

Comment: @PaulFrost: could you sketch the argument or give a reference why the local degree equals to the covering degree up to $\pm 1 $ factor?

Comment: I think I have found the answer: The function $M \to \{\pm1 \}$ which associates to points of $m \in M$ the sign of the determinant $D_mf$ is locally constant. $M$ is connected, the map locally constant, so this map is even constant

Comment: You should now answer your own question. @user7391733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having fixed orientations on $M$ and $N$ the correct statement becomes for every $y \in N$:  $$ \vert \text{deg}(y)(f) \vert  = \vert f^{−1}(y) \vert  $$

That's because the function $M \to \{\pm1 \}$ which associates to every $x \in M$ the sign of the determinant of derivative $D_x f$ (-which is nowhere zero, because a covering is a local diffeomeorphism) is a locally constant function and because $M$ was assumed to be connected, this function is even constant.